# python psutil vs top

Tags: python, top

I'm confused about the difference between CPU percentage as measured by the `top` command and by the `psutil.cpu_percent`

Here are two samples from the same second :

**Python**

```
 >>> while pct := psutil.cpu_percent(interval=2) :
 ...   print(pct)
 ... 
 6.9
 8.2
 7.0
 7.3
 7.0
 8.7
 9.2
 11.2
```

The highest measure is 6.9. This is specified as `Return a float representing the current **system-wide** CPU utilization as a percentage.`

**top**

Here is the %CPU column from the second iteration of the `top` command.

```
 %CPU
 29.4
 5.9
 5.9
 0.0
```

`%CPU` is specified as  `The  task's  share  of  the  elapsed CPU time since the last screen update, expressed as a percentage of total CPU time.`

Why are these two representations so different?